# Finding the method of moment for Beta given a pdf and n random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, expected-value, moment-problem

I have this tough question in my exam prep textbook and I've been struggling with it

```
() = {( + 1), 0 <  < 1 where  > −1.
         0,        ℎ,
```

And need to find the Method of Moment estimator for Beta but I'm really struggling can anyone help me out with the derivation

Comment: What have you tried?  For example, what is $E[X]$? In any case I suspect  your density should be $(\beta+1)x^\beta$

Comment: I tried integrating and keep getting messed up on the integral

Comment: $\int x \,f(x)\, dx = \int\limits_0^1 x \,(\beta+1)x^\beta\, dx = (\beta+1)\int\limits_0^1x^{\beta+1}\, dx$ is not difficult to evaluate